# How to convert this Series of string to a Series of numbers

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

I have a pandas series as followed:

```
series = pd.Series(['', '', '$ 200,000', '$ -320,000','$ 700,000','','$ -10,000'])
```

I need to convert all string values in the series to integers or float by removing `'$ '` and commas. I have tried the following:

```
for i in series:
    if '$ ' in i:
        i=i.replace('$ ',"")
series = pd.to_numeric(series, errors='coerce')
```

However, the replace method doesn't change the series. I'm not yet sure if `pd.to_numeric` method is gonna help me concert the series to numbers or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `replace` and `to_numeric`

- Remove anything that **isn't** a digit, period/decimal point, or minus sign.
- Using `pandas.Series.str.replace` defaults to using regex

---

```
pd.to_numeric(series.str.replace('[^0-9\.-]', ''))

0         NaN
1         NaN
2    200000.0
3   -320000.0
4    700000.0
5         NaN
6    -10000.0
dtype: float64
```

Equivalently: `pandas.Series.replace` has to be told that using regex is needed.

```
pd.to_numeric(series.replace('[^0-9\.-]', '', regex=True))
```